# Android getExternalCacheDir() returns null

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-sdcard

I am trying to implement the best practices described in [Loading Bitmaps effeciently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

I've run into trouble because this line:

```
Utils.getExternalCacheDir(context)
```

inside of **DiskLruCache.java** is returning null, which means I get `NullPointerException` when I try to call .getPath()

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Despite the somewhat cryptic `NullPointerException`  that gets thrown the actual issues is that my application did not have WRITE_EXTERNAL permission, so the system was rejecting my attempt to use the ExternalDir for caching. Unfortunately this was happening at a low enough level in the code used in Displaying Bitmaps Effeciently that the Exception does not indicate `SecurityException` as it normally would if one were trying to write to the SD card without the proper permission.

To fix simply add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to your manifest.

Comment: On android 4.4+ this permission is no longer required for cache purpose

You can use this permission with the maxSdkVersion paremeter:

 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: And on some lollipop builds this is broken, so I suggest removing the max sdk ... Silly I know

Comment: @Climbatize my app has reported the same crash for SDK versions 19 and 22.

Comment: @DroidHeaven - Interesting.  My app has had a failure based on the same cause (i.e. getExternalCacheDir returning null) on SDK19 also.  And it has STORAGE permission, which should imply WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, so there is clearly something else that causes this method to return null in some cases... (edit: I see there is an answer below that suggests the potential problem...)

Answer (score 7):

This can also happen if you're running on a device or emulator without any external storage.

Comment: At least this is unprofitable to propagate such devices on user's market

Comment: Changed my answer, android devices without external storage aren't that rare. Can also happen if the device has external storage, but the card is not present or unmounted.